# Big-O of a function that has a nested loop affected by outer loop

Tags: big-o

```
for(int i = 0; i < N*N; i++) {
   for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      //something O(1)
   }
}
```

So I was trying to find big O of this function.

The outer loop is O(N^2) alone, and the inner loop goes from 0 to N^2. So I was thinking this would make the whole thing O(N^4). Am I correct in thinking this?